# Customising absolutely positioned FontAwesome markers on an Image (map)

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have absolutely positioned markers on a map using FontAwesome so I can resize the map and the images stay in the same relative position.

Each has a number and the FontAwesome character is a circle but I am looking to use a pseudo-element and position the number in the circle and have a single marker.

Is this possible? I have tried many different approaches and none have worked for me.

Please see example below;

```css
.map-marker {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#one {
    top: 70px;
    left: 20px;
}
#one:after {
    content: "\f111";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
#two {
    top: 50px;
    left: 260px;
}
#two:after {
    content: "\f111";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="map_container">
  <img src="http://geology.com/world/world-map-clickable.gif"/>
  <a href="#"><div id="one" class="map-marker" aria-hidden="true">1</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div id="two" class="map-marker" aria-hidden="true">2</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not call the font awesome html for your map pins instead? You can call pngs from a static path, you can call html as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `a` in absolute position then using before (or after) on it. Like that you will have two different elements inside it and you can play with z-index of each one to make the pseudo-element below the number.

You can also simplify your CSS since the pseudo element is the same for **one** and **two**

```css
.map-marker {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.map-marker span {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color:#fff;
}
.map-marker:before {
  content: "\f111";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: relative;
  right: -14px;
  z-index: 0;
}
#one {
  top: 70px;
  left: 20px;
}

#two {
  top: 50px;
  left: 260px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="map_container">
  <img src="http://geology.com/world/world-map-clickable.gif" />
  <a href="#" id="one" class="map-marker">
    <span aria-hidden="true">1</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="two" class="map-marker">
    <span aria-hidden="true">2</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution with some value adds. Thanks!